# What is MemAlloc in C? How does it differ from malloc?

Tags: c, memory-management

I have faced this question many times, but I have no idea about it. I searched many sites. The information I gathered is:

> MemAlloc is a free memory allocation tool. It allows you to stress and test your Windows operating system by requesting any amount of memory you want.

> `void * Memalloc(ulong size,int flags);`
>
> Allocates memory in the context of OllyDbg. Requests are redirected to GlobalAlloc(). Use it to allocate larger chunks of memory. Call Memfree() to free this memory.`

These information doesn't answer a my queries, and the concept is still not very clear to me. It will be kind of you if you describe the purpose of memalloc.

I have another question: if it is memory allocation tool what is the difference between malloc vs memalloc?

Comment: What API is that?  Some clue perhaps?

Comment: The two quotes you have there come from two different things called memalloc and are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 4):

> OllyDbg is a 32-bit assembler level analysing debugger for Microsoft® Windows®. Emphasis on binary code analysis makes it particularly useful in cases where source is unavailable.

This is a debug library that contains memory allocation methods like `Memalloc` which is able to **detect memory leaks**. Memalloc looks for me like a wrapper over Windows `GlobalAlloc`.

So what is the difference to `malloc`? It is unknown, however it seems to me not being so fast as most malloc implementations can do since it uses relative outdated `GlobalAlloc` whereas most malloc implementations allocates large chunks with `VirtualAlloc`.

See what MSDN says about `GlobalAlloc`:

> Note  The global functions have greater overhead and provide fewer features than other memory management functions. New applications should use the heap functions unless documentation states that a global function should be used. For more information, see Global and Local Functions.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that malloc is part of the C standard library and exists for any C compiler/tool chain, whereas MemAlloc is not part of the C standard.

Apparently, according to the quotations you give, there are certain libraries that provide a function which is called MemAlloc, and which I guess allocates memory with some additional functionality (you'll need to read the documentation for each library to know the exact difference).
This function itself might even use malloc.